# Python call to external software command

Tags: python

I have a slight problem. I have a software which has a command with two inputs. The command is: `maf2hal inputfile outputfile.`

I need to call this command from a Python script. The Python script asks the user for path of input file and path of output file and stores them in two variables.The problem is that when I call the command `maf2hal` giving the two variable names as the arguments, the error I get is cannot locate file.

Is there a way around this? Here's my code:

```
folderfound = "n" # looping condition
while (folderfound == "n"):
    path = raw_input("Enter path of file to convert (with the extension) > ")
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print "\tERROR! file not found. Maybe file doesn't exist or no extension was provided. Try again!\n"
    else:
        print "\tFile found\n"
        folderfound = "y"

folderfound = "y" # looping condition
while (folderfound == "y"):
    outName = raw_input("Enter path of output file to be created > ")
    if os.path.exists(outName):
        print "\tERROR! File already exists \n\tEither delete the existing file or enter a new file name\n\n"
    else:
        print "Creating output file....\n"
        outputName = outName + ".maf"
        print "Done\n"
        folderfound = "n"
hal_input = outputName #inputfilename, 1st argument
hal_output = outName + ".hal" #outputfilename, 2nd argument

call("maf2hal hal_input hal_output", shell=True)
```

Comment: try printing the varaibles "hal_input" and "hal_output". It could be an issue with "/" and relative paths

Comment: I tried printing too and it was fine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
call("maf2hal hal_input hal_output", shell=True)
```

It should be:

```
call(["maf2hal", hal_input, hal_output])
```

Otherwise you're giving "hal_input" as the actual file name, rather than using the variable.

You should not use `shell=True` unless absolutely necessary, and in this case it is not only unnecessary, it is pointlessly inefficient.  Just call the executable directly, as above.

For bonus points, use `check_call()` instead of `call()`, because the former will actually check the return value and raise an exception if the program failed.  Using `call()` doesn't, so errors may go unnoticed.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems. Your first reported error was that the call to the shell can't find the `maf2hal` program - that sounds like a path issue. You need to verify that the command is in the path of the shell that is being created.

Second, your `call` is passing the words "hal_input" and "hal_output". You'll need to build that command up first to pass the values of those variables;

```
cmd = "maf2hal {0} {1}".format(hal_input, hal_output)
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is literally trying to open a file called `hal_input`, not using the contents of your variable with the same name. It looks like you're using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute, so you can just change it to `call(["maf2hal", hal_input, hal_output], shell=True)` to use the contents.

Answer (score 2):

at the end of your code:

```
call("maf2hal hal_input hal_output", shell=True)
```

you are literally calling that string, not the executable and then those paths, you need to concatenate your strings together first, either by adding them of using .join
eg:

```
call("maf2hal " + hal_input + " " + hal_output", shell=True)
```

or

```
call("maf2hal ".join(hal_input, " ", hal_output), shell=True)
```

Comment: While true, I would not recommend constructing the command string in this way. Using `format()` or passing the arguments and program in a list as suggested above is a lot more readable.

Comment: i don't use the subprocess module much, i had forgotten you could pass it a list as the first argument.